# No Desktop after version upgrade

Tags: upgrade, lightdm, login-screen, gdm

Thinks look dark!

After doing a system upgrade from 22.04 to 23.04 my laptop displays a black screen, not even wallpaper. However, I can login via ssh. I've flailed about in ignorance and gdm.service says he's running. But he does show a couple messages from gkr-pam about not having a password & not unlocking a keyring. (I'd like to enter my password, but I cannot.)

Can anyone point me to a backgrounder on repairing this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to boot Ubuntu in nomodeset mode, which is a kernel parameter that disables the loading of the graphics drivers until the system is fully booted. This may help you to bypass the black screen and access the graphical interface, where you can install or update the appropriate drivers for your graphics card. To boot in nomodeset mode, you need to follow these steps:

Start your computer and press the Right Shift when booting up, to get the Grub menu.
Select the Ubuntu option and press E to edit it.
Find the line that starts with linux and add nomodeset at the end of it.
Press Ctrl+X or F10 to boot with the modified parameters.